# How to extrapolate columns out to a known expiry date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Struggling with this one (even to explain with clarity) and can't find anything similar. I have a table which is dynamically generated in my application, with clients and tradeid columns, then I have a number of columns representing dates into the future until the trade expires with a value.

I'm trying to populate the columns up until this expiry date that contains the value with the same amount. The below demo illustration of what I'm attempting to achieve will hopefully make more sense.

```
-- this demo table represents my original data

create table #t1(
[ClientName] varchar(10),
[TradeID] int,
[01/11/2021] int,
[01/12/2021] int,
[01/01/2022] int,
[01/02/2022] int,
[01/03/2022] int,
)

insert into #t1 values ('A',132,NULL,NULL,100,NULL,NULL)
insert into #t1 values ('B',1287,NULL,50,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into #t1 values ('C ',7484,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,150)
insert into #t1 values ('D ',456,NULL,100,NULL,NULL,NULL)

-- this demo table represents my desired outcome

create table #t2(
[ClientName] varchar(10),
[TradeID] int,
[01/11/2021] int,
[01/12/2021] int,
[01/01/2022] int,
[01/02/2022] int,
[01/03/2022] int,
)

insert into #t2 values ('A',132,100,100,100,NULL,NULL)
insert into #t2 values ('B',1287,50,50,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into #t2 values ('C ',7484,150,150,150,150,150)
insert into #t2 values ('D ',456,100,100,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

[image: screenshot of before and after]

Comment: In truth, creating a table with each date is just a bad idea. Why not use a normalised design?

Comment: As mentioned but not actually explained by Larnu there, you should really be storing your data with `ClientName`, `TradeID` and `ExpiryDate` as the columns and a row for each corresponsing data point.  If you can, change your data structure to something like this to save a lot of difficulties like the one you have here.  If you can't, you're going to need a very suboptimal solution.

Comment: The SQL language has a very strict rule requiring you to know the number of columns in the results of a query _before looking at any data in the table_. That makes this table design a poor choice, because you're rarely going to about what dates are active in advance. Instead, you want a table with three total columns: one for ClientName, TradeId, and Date, and a row for every combination of these.

Comment: As a rule of thumb... humans prefer fewer tables/rows, where the tables are wider as a result. That's fine... you can show data to the humans that way in the presentation tier. But the machine where you actually store the data does better with more tables that are narrower and have more rows for the same data. That's how you should design your schema.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually referred to a a SQL "cross-tab" query.

Questions:

- How many dates need to be returned by the query?  More dates means more columns, slower performance and increased SQL complexity
- Are the dates fixed?  Or are the dates the minimum trade date in the set of trades + 30 days?
- How many trades would be in a data set?
- Is another application displaying the query results, and can that application build out the cross-tab?

For these data requests, once you get beyond 20 to 30 columns, they become too complex for ANSI SQL.